# What are the best algorithms to compute an itinerary for a public transport app?

Tags: algorithm, directions

I am creating an app for a public transports app, and I would need to compute itineraries.

However, I am not sure about what algorithm to use? A classic pathfinding algorithm like Dijkstra's or A*?

The fact that I have to handle both

1. *basic* pathfinding (stops to stops without walking)
2. *advanced* pathfinding (walking between stops)
3. *harder* combining both into one algorithm

makes me wonder what to choose precisely.

Thanks for helping

Mods: Feel free to move the question to the appropriate place if my post isn't where it belongs

Comment: Combining all situations in a single algorithm is a "no-toil": the transportation mean characteristics are "hard-coded" in the edge costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijkstra vs A* :

A* is faster to compute but can give wrong result, Dijkstra will find the shortest/fastest path all the time.

I'd use Dijkstra for that application.

pseudo-code :

```
class Path
{
    List<Node> nodesOfThePath;
    int length;
}

List<Path> paths = findAllLinksRelatedTo(startPoint); //You have to write a function to get the nodes linked to the given point
paths.Sort(); //sort using the length, ascending

while (paths.length > 0)
{
    if (paths[0].getLastestNode() == FinalPoint)
        return (paths[0]); //this is the shortest one

    List<Path> tempPaths = findAllLinksRelatedTo(paths[0].getLastestNode()); //get all nodes related to the lastest one of the shortest actual path or null if none was found
    paths.removeAt(0); //remove the shortest path
    foreach (tempPath in tempPaths)
        paths.Add(tempPath);
    paths.sort();
}
return (null); //no path found
```

Comment: Thanks ! One more question, I would just treat street intersections as nodes and their cost as time is that correct ?

Comment: Yes it is correct. If you have any kind of intersection, that's a node. The weight of a link between 2 nodes depends of your criterias (length, time to travel, etc...)

Comment: A\* also always gives the shortest path, if your heuristic is consistent and admissible. A\* is just a generalisation of Dijkstra.